# fs.writeFile corrupt, using base64 string

Tags: node.js, fs

The file writes ok but Photos says it is an unsupported format. The file also seems much smaller than I expect (16kb).

```
router.post('/image/upload/gamethumb',
(req, res) => {
    const destination = keys.imageLocation + "cards/";
    console.log(req.body.image);
    fs.writeFile(destination + req.query.title + ".png", req.body.image, 'base64',
    () => {res.json({image: 'Uploaded'});
}
    )
});
```

the start of req.body.image is:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA ...
```

and renders fine if I paste it into chrome.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `req.body.image` contains a *Data URL*, which is more than just the image body. The base64 image data starts after the comma. Your current code accidentally encodes the Data URL header (`data:image/png` etc.) as if it was part of the image, which it isn't.

Simple fix:

```
const base64Data = req.body.image.split('base64,')[1];
fs.writeFile(destination + req.query.title + ".png", base64Data, 'base64', ...);
```

(This code assumes the incoming image is always correct; you could add some additional logic to ensure the prefix actually is `data:image/png;base64,`, etc., if you wish.)

Answer (score 2):

`req.body.image` string not a real image.

Let remove header, then save image string to a file as a image

```
let base64Image = base64String.split(';base64,').pop();
fs.writeFile(req.query.title + ".png", base64Image, {encoding: 'base64'}, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('File created');
});
```